# How do I remove the Vertices but keep the face shape? (Blender 2.82 BETA)

Tags: modeling

I am making a lizard dude but he has patches of vertices, re-meshing didn't seem to work.

[image: re-meshing didn't seem to work]
[image]

Comment: Please use only tags that are relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

To get even sized Faces I recommend using voxel Remesh. Other options would be the "Remesh" and "Decimate" Modifiers. Please note that these methods won't give you a perfect topology. Only planning ahead when creating your model does.

[image: Voxel Remesh]

Comment: Thanks I'll try out.

Comment: I tried it out and I don't think I am going to do that, Should I restart and remake the mesh manually?

Comment: To me it looks like you applied a subsurface modifier at some point. If you have a file from before you applied it, hit Alt + J to convert the triangle faces into quads. I don't have any other advise on how to improve your existing topology unfortunatly.